# C++ Using KeccakCode Package

Tags: c++, linux, keccak

I downloaded some post quantum algorithms from NIST and tested them. Some codes need to use Keccak package, so I downloaded it.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage
```

When I tried to build the required static library,

```
$ make generic64/libkeccak.a
```

I got an error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'generic64/libkeccak.a'.  Stop.
```

Did I miss other steps?  How can I fix it?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no target called "libkeccak". The very short example says "make <target>/libXKCP.so". (And quoting the Readme: "The list of targets can be found at the end of Makefile.build or by running make without parameters.")

Comment: I solved this problem according to your advice. Thank you for your help.!!!!